# Ignore the string enclosed in parentheses in regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

Ignore the string enclosed in parentheses in regex

```
    String: 
    This is an example (test 1):
    
    Regex tried:
    ^\s*([\w\s]+\s+example(?:\s\(\w+\s\d+\)|):)
    
    Expected output:
    This is an example:
```

Comment: Do you just want to remove the pair(s) of parentheses and the enclosed string(s)?

Comment: Your regex has "example" in it. Is there some requirement the replacement is only done when there is "example" in the input? Also, your regex requires that the part in parentheses consists of a word followed by a number, and that after the parentheses there is a colon. None of this is specified in your question. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly  use regex for above requirement.You have to extract out all the string before opening bracket and and after closing bracket. and then concatenate  extracted  strings.

`(.*)?` -> will match everything before .

`\(` -> will match entire before opening bracket `(` and store it in backreference `\1`.

`\(.*?\)` -> will match entire string  within and including `(` and `)` .

`(.*)` -> will match entire string after the closing bracket and store it in backreference `\2` .

Now this backreferences stored string will concatenated  to get desire result.

```
import re

regex = r"(.+)?\(.*?\)(.*)"

test_str = ("This is an example (test 1):\n")

subst = "\\1\\2"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
   print (result)
```